# Matlab `corr` gives different results on the same dataset. Is floating-point calculation deterministic?

Tags: matlab, floating-point

I am using Matlab's `corr` function to calculate the correlation of a dataset. While the results agree within the double point accuracy (<10^-14), they are not exactly the same even on the same computer for different runs.

Is floating-point calculation deterministic? Where is the source of the randomness?

Comment: Could you post some code or data? I ran the example in the `corr` help documentation multiple times and get exactly the same result every time. Are you sure the numbers are exactly the same or are they also being calculated?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

Floating point arithmetic, as in a sequence of operations `+`, `*`, etc. is deterministic. However in this case, linear algebra libraries (BLAS, LAPACK, etc) are most likely being used, which may not be: for example, matrix multiplication is typically not performed as a "triple loop" as some references would have you believe, but instead matrices are split up into blocks that are optimised for maximum performance based on things like cache size. Therefore, you will get different sequences of operations, with different intermediate rounding, which will give slightly different results. Typically, however, the variation in these results is smaller than the total rounding error you are incurring.

I have to admit, I am a little bit surprised that you get different results on the same computer, but it is difficult to know why without knowing what the library is doing (IIRC, Matlab uses the Intel BLAS libraries, so you could look at their documentation).